# History.listen is not firing in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, history

History.listen is not working in react application

```
history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(`The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`)
  console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`)
})
```

Using react-router-dom @v5

Comment: where/how r u using it? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: .listen should not fire, it listen for the event. To fire an event, you need to use history.push or click <Link> element. You need to show the code where you fire the event.

Comment: Where do you get history from?